# loading multiple jar files dynamically using java.util.serviceLoader

Tags: java

I am trying to write an web application which loads jar file dynamically without starting the war file.

I am creating multiple jar file.
All jar file implements a common interface.
all jar files have META-INF/service -> package.interface name

The web application works fine if there is only one jar, if i add another jar file, it prints the result of older jar file. It wont print the result of second jar file

```
jar 1 

name: pluggin1
src
 -> test
  -> TestInterface
  -> TestInterfaceImpl
 META-INF
 > services
     -> test.TestInterface(this is the file name)
     -> content of the file = test.TestInterfaceImpl

jar 2 

 name: pluggin2
 src
  -> test
    -> TestInterface
    -> helloImpl
 META-INF
   -> services
       -> test.TestInterface(this is the file name)
          -> content of the file = test.helloImpl


   main class which loads contents of jar file dynamically


main.java

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("junaid");

    String res = getInstance().getDefinition("junaid");

    System.out.println("asdasd= "+ res);
}

private static ManagePlugins service;
private ServiceLoader<TestInterface> loader;

  /**
     * Creates a new instance of DictionaryService
     */
    private ManagePlugins() {
        loader = ServiceLoader.load(TestInterface.class);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the singleton static instance of DictionaryService.
     */
    public static synchronized ManagePlugins getInstance() {
        if (service == null) {
            service = new ManagePlugins();
        }
        return service;
    }


  /**
     * Retrieve definitions from the first provider
     * that contains the word.
     */
    public String getDefinition(String className) {
        String definition = null;

        try {
            Iterator<SimplePlugin> dictionaries = loader.iterator();
            while (definition == null && dictionaries.hasNext()) {
                SimplePlugin d = dictionaries.next();
                definition = d.getName();
                System.out.println("definition = "+ definition);
            }
        } catch (ServiceConfigurationError serviceError) {
            definition = null;
            serviceError.printStackTrace();

        }
        return definition;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the `test.TestInterface` class is included **in both jars**. That's surely the cause of your problem. A class (or interface) must be available just in one place in the same runtime. I.E.: Must not be repeated in several places.

Remove one of them, or take it to a common library.

Comment: Hello Santi, My requirement is to add jar files dynamically to the web project without restarting the application. If i need to modify a particular jar every time i add a new jar, it defeats the purpose.                                             or is there any other alternative way to achieve this.

Comment: Hello Juniad. No, that's not the intention. You just must package **the interface** in a single jar. And then, add as many implementations as you want (each one in its own jar, to accomplish the specification of ServiceLoader). And take care not to include again the interface in any of them jars.

Comment: Hello Santi, now i only have the interface in one jar file. but still it behaving the same, it prints the output of the jar which has the interface.

Comment: And how do you add jar files dynamically?

Comment: i just copy the jar file into WEBINF/lib folder. I also tried having both the jar file and then restarted the application still same behavior.

Comment: OK. I'll try to reproduce, tough it'll take me a while.

Comment: I think I got it: I spotted two suspicious details in your code: First is the condition in the `while`: it includes `definition==null` so It would exit after one iteration. Second is that you should iterate over `TestInterface` objects, not `SamplePlugin` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I had two separate jar files that implemented the interface to be loaded, but only the first jar file found was being processed. The second jar was ignored.

I too was using the lazy load iterator (per your example):

```
...
Iterator<SimplePlugin> dictionaries = loader.iterator();
  while (definition == null && dictionaries.hasNext()) {
    SimplePlugin d = dictionaries.next();
...
```

The problem was fixed by replacing the looping code with:

```
...
for(SimplePlugin d : loader) {
...
```

After this simple code change, both jars were being discovered.